# Handling empty xml tags using java

Tags: java, xml

i have an xml as below.

```
<stat>
    <Parents>
        <Parent>
            <parentName></parentName>
            <occupation></occupation>
        </Parent>
        <Parent>
            <parentName>Brian</parentName>
            <occupation>Doctor</occupation>
        </Parent>
    </Parents>
     <Parents/>
    <Parents>
        <Parent>
            <parentName></parentName>
            <occupation></occupation>
        </Parent>
        <Parent/>
    </Parents>
</stat>
```

I need to validate the xml file using java in based on the parents values.When ever the xml file contains empty parents block for e.g: `<Parents/> or  <Parents> <Parent><parentName></parentName><occupation></occupation></Parent></Parents>`.I need to throw an exception saying xml is not valid.How to implement the requirment using either xpath or some approach with out performance issue.
Your help appreciated.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: You could do this with regex easily. Try it out and then let's see how we can help.

Comment: [First Link](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t169284-xpath-expression-to-test-for-empty-node.html) of [google search (xpath get nodes with empty text)](http://www.google.com/search?q=xpath+get+nodes+with+empty+text) looks useful.

Comment: No, please do NOT even think of using regexps. XML should be handled with XML tools, since raw textual representation != logical model. Besides, regexps actually can not easily even deal with matching of start/end tags; that's DFA 101 fact

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd recommend you to take a look on XSD. Using XSD you can define which tags and how many such tags may appear in your XML. Once you are done just validate XML: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPDOM8.html

```
d
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from XSD or RelaxNG schemas (which should allow specifying acceptable models; and empty one not being one of them, can report it), this would be easy to deal with Stax XMLStreamReader (javax.xml.stream.) as well. Read any tutorial, and check for START_ELEMENT/END_ELEMENT pairs (with 'parents' as local name).